# When I append line to file in php, the previous lines have been deleted, how do I prevent this?

Tags: php, file

Basically, I just want to add a line to a text file, but when I do it it deletes the previous content of the file.

How can I add a line to a text file without deleting the previous content?

```
<?php

    $template = $_POST["template"];

    $templateFile = fopen("templates.txt", "a");
    file_put_contents("templates.txt", $template);
    fclose($templateFile);
    //header function to go back to my original page where the form was

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to open the file with `fopen()` if you use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), it already does that for you:

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

Also you want to set the flag `FILE_APPEND`, so you append your content, e.g.

```
file_put_contents("templates.txt", $template, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing c style `fopen` `fwrite` and `fclose` with PHP specific `file_put_contents` function.
You have to choose one.

Using the first method you have to `fopen` the file, specifying name, and mode, writing on the file using `fwrite`, and closing the file with `fclose`.

Alternatively you can use the PHP `file_put_contents` ([implementation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/250938e2d35fc54161a18167b7901c5e3b574371/ext/standard/file.c#L568), [documentation](http://php.net/manual/it/function.file-put-contents.php)), and as you can see the function itself checks that the file is a regular file, that is not locked by another application, writes the content, and close the file.

TL;DR
To append to a file in PHP use the following code:

```
file_put_contents("myfile.txt", "content", FILE_APPEND);
```

Remember that writing postdata to a file is not secure!